# Запустить bash скрипт через php

Tags: php, linux, bash, exec

Возможно ли как то это

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cartoon/

Запустить из под php, через exec например?

Answer (score 1):

Для ImegeMagic есть расширение php. Его нужно установить php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php также может понадобится gostscript иначе imagic может не работать. После этого можно использовать imagic как класс php или cli с помощью exec команжа convert

exec('convert input.pdf output.jpg')